# Apply CSS elements to only some pages in Mkdocs

Tags: html, css, mkdocs

I'm using mkdocs with the material theme to generate documentation.

For certain pages I would like to have section numbers.  I'm using the following to generate section numbers.

[is there a way to make the headings, sections and subsections numbering in markdown language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029165/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-headings-sections-and-subsections-numbering-in-markd)

This works well, but it applies to all pages when I put the specified CSS into `extras.css`.  I have pages which should not include section numbering for headings.

Is there a way to specify which pages certain elements in `extras.css` should be applied?

Answer (score 1):

My first answer would be to tell you to create a class in your CSS `extra.css` file and add "section numbers" as an attribute. And then add this class to the pages you want to have "section numbers".

As a complementary answer :
This link might help you, it basically tells that you can create a custom theme as a mkdocs theme.

[Customizing Your Theme - in Mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/customizing-your-theme/)